# PHP Override an array on file

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `php` file that contains an array.

```
//config.php

return [
    'name' => 'XXXX',
    'phone' => '000',
    'email' => 'YYYY',
    ...
];
```

now i want to override `config.php` file and change `email` values to `ZZZZ` from another `php` file like `index.php`

Comment: You want to permanently change the file? Or do you want to change the values of the array after the config.php file has returned the values?

Comment: @Ethan22 i want to permanently change the file.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It seems like a pretty unusual approach.

Comment: @Don'tPanic because i want to use it as lang file.

Comment: PHP files (and config files, ordinarily) are not supposed to be changed on-the-fly like this. You could create another file which includes this file, changes a value, and then returns it again.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen actually i want to use it as little database

Comment: Why not use e.g. the DBA functions?

Comment: @tsnorri because there is unlimited type of data like this that i need it

Comment: Serialize the data before using the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If XXXX is going to be a placeholder, you could do:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents("path/to/file");
$new_file_contents = str_replace("XXXX","ZZZZ", $file_contents);
file_put_contents("path/to/file", $new_file_contents);
```

Comment: what if i had multiple 'XXXX' value on my file?

Answer (score 1):

PHP files are not supposed to be changed on-the-fly like this. It is technically possible, but that does not mean you should do it.

A decent solution that does not go around changing your code nilly-willy would be to create another file that modifies the configuration file and then returns it again:

```
// config-filtered.php
$config = include 'config.php';
$config['email'] = 'ZZZZ'; // Or = $_SESSION['user_email']; for example
return $config;

// index.php
$config = include 'config-filtered.php';
echo "Hello {$config['name']}, your email is {$config['email']}";
```

Comment: is this going to save on ``config.php`` file?

Comment: No, it will not. PHP files are not suitable to be used as a "little database".

Comment: laravel uses php files as language files , and i want to change language files dynamically.